# sent an image displayed on the page to the django server

Tags: html, django

I have an image which is displayed on the page when the image is clicked a modal opens containing a button. I would like by clicking on the button sent the selected image to the django server. The image tag and the button tag are in different tag structures with others tag so i can't use `<form action="" method="post"> ... </form>`.

```
<div>
    <button id="myBtn" type="button">
    <img src="path_image" width="200" height="200" alt="description" id="my-image">
    </button>
 </div>
 <!-- ... --> 
 <!-- button that is in a modal -->
 <div> 
    <button id="sendBtn" type="button"> upload image </button>
 </div>
```

How can i get the image and send it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file input to send the image, like the example below

```
<form method="post">
<input type="file">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```